# RStudio does not retain chosen font

Tags: fonts, rstudio

I'm using RStudio 1.2.5033 on Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I close and reopen RStudio, the editor font reverts back to the default font (Ubuntu Mono). That happens regardless of what other font I choose through the Global Options > Appearance menu. How do I make RStudio keep another font?

Comment: Strange...it works on my ubuntu laptop. Maybe stupid precision, but do you `apply` the change?

Comment: I do apply the changes. May it have to do with the font itself? I removed the original font from the system (PT Mono) to replace it with its bold version, which I downloaded. RStudio would only offer the regular face when I had them both installed (apparently because the regular and bold versions have the same name?).